# Cypher query for return node which <some_field> = max(<some_field>) value out of a group of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have the following data:

```
field1, field2
1,1
1,4
1,3
2,5
2,2
3,1
3,8
3,9
3,11
4,4
```

How can I write a cypher query to return the node that has the biggest value of `field2` for a given `field1`. i.e.

```
1,4
2,5
3,11
4,4
```

My attempts so far have resulted in the following  (which doesn't work):

```
MATCH(a:A)
WITH COLLECT({field1: a.field1, field2: MAX(a.field2)}) as rowInfos 
UNWIND rowInfos as rowInfo
WITH rowInfo.field1 as field1, rowInfo.field2 as maxField2
MATCH (a)
WHERE a.field1 = field1 AND a.field2 = maxField2
return a
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the query to achieve this is rather simple:

```
MATCH(b:A)
WITH b.field1 as field1, MAX(b.field2) as field2
WHERE b.field1 = field1
MATCH (b)
WHERE b.field1 = field1 AND b.field2 = field2
RETURN b
```